# Configuring Kestrel on .NET 7.0 to do API calls over HTTPS from a Client PC on the Local Network

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, .net-7.0

I would like some guidance with my issue. I am trying to configure kestrel on my dotnet core 7.0 api application to do API calls over HTTPS. The main reason why I need to configure kestrel is that I want to be able to connect from a client PC and be able to use functionalities such as using the webcam, but in order to do so, I need to setup a custom domain so that the client PC does not use the localhost URL to do those API calls.

The certificate for my custom domain has already been create and store directly on my C:/ drive, it is password protected with a GUID define in my .csproj file and the path as been defined in the appsettings.Development.json file in my project like so:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "databaseConnection": "Azure_SQL_connection_string"
  },
  "CertPath": "c:\\inventorynexless.pfx"
}
```

I was following this guide: [Custom Local Domain using HTTPS, Kestrel & ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetplaybook.com/custom-local-domain-using-https-kestrel-asp-net-core/), but as you can see, he uses .NET Core 3.1 and the structure of the files in the project has changed. In .NET Core 7.0 the program.cs and startup.cs file have been merged.

Here is my HostConfig.cs file:

```
public static class HostConfig
{
  public static string? CertPath { get; set; }
  public static string? CertPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my program.cs file:

```
using Dot7.API.CRUD.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(opt =>
{
  opt.ListenAnyIP(5000);
  opt.ListenAnyIP(5001, listOpt =>
  {
    listOpt.UseHttps(builder.Configuration["CertPath"], builder.Configuration["CertPassword"]);
  });
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("Cors", p =>
  {
    p.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod();
  });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<databaseContext>(options =>
{
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("databaseConnection"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseCors("Cors");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And I am getting the following exceptions:

```
C:\Desktop\dotnet7-vue3-crud - Developpment - HTTPS\Dot7.API.CRUD\Program.cs(11,22): warning CS8604: Possible null reference a
rgument for parameter 'fileName' in 'ListenOptions ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, string fileName, st 
ring? password)'. [C:\Desktop\dotnet7-vue3-crud - Developpment - HTTPS\Dot7.API.CRUD\Dot7.API.CRUD.csproj]
Unhandled exception. System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificatePal.FromBlobOrFile(ReadOnlySpan`1 rawData, String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
agnosticSource diagnosticSource)
agnosticSource diagnosticSource)
agnosticSource diagnosticSource)
agnosticSource diagnosticSource)
agnosticSource diagnosticSource)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl..ctor(IOptions`1 options, IEnumerable`1 transportFactories, IEnumerable`1 multiplexedFactories, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DiagnosticSource diagnosticSource)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InvokeWithManyArguments(RuntimeConstructorInfo ci, Int32 argCount, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.get_ServerFeatures()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication..ctor(IHost host)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Desktop\dotnet7-vue3-crud - Developpment - HTTPS\Dot7.API.CRUD\Program.cs:line 34
```

Since I am a beginner, I am trying to figure things out as I go. I don't really understand what this error message means and how to debug it. Can you somebody help me out with this issue?

PS: if you require additional files to inspect the issue, don't hesitate to ask.

I tried looking for examples online, but most of the reference material uses an older version of .NET Core and as a beginner it is not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem is that you move `inventorynexless.pfx` to the root of the `C:\` drive, and your application does not have sufficient permissions to read it.

You can store `inventorynexless.pfx` on the other disks, or create a folder in your project to temporarily store it for testing purposes only.